# exec() failing with return code 11

Tags: php, exec

I have the following PHP script that isolates my issue:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$code = 0;
$output = array();
exec('"../vendor/bin/PdfGenie" code.rq', $output, $code);

echo $code . "\n";
print_r($output);
```

The `PdfGenie` executable is reading the contents of `code.rq` and tries to create a pdf document in the same directory.

When I run the code in my browser, I get this:

```
11
Array
(
)
```

And it doesn't create the file.

However if I ssh into the server and execute `php tst.php` (with or without root) I get:

```
0
Array
(
)
```

And the output file is written just fine. Additionally if I execute the same command (`"../vendor/bin/PdfGenie" code.rq`) directly from ssh, that works too.

I suspected that, maybe apache is running the PHP script with a different user, and have tried all the options on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771586/how-to-check-what-user-php-is-running-as) to get the user that it could be, but they all gave me the same user that I was sshing in with and it worked just fine on.

What's different (or how can I figure out what's different) about when apache executes my PHP script, that's causing this error code 11?

Comment: What does the pdfgenie documentation say about exit code 11?

Comment: @Michael Hampton nothing :(